# How to set images From Firebase-Firestore collection to React-Native-Image-Gallery

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, image-gallery, react-native-firebase

I'm building a mobile app, I want to set my images from firestore-collections to my react-native-image-gallery. I already get my all link of images from firestore, but I couldn't solve how to set them to my image-gallery. My react-native-image-gallery codes with images are:

```
<SafeAreaView>
    {/* home screen navbar --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/}
    <View style={[{height: '100%%', backgroundColor:'white'}]}>
        <Gallery
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black' }}
            images={[
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/74.-BEYZA-MEMİŞ.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/1.-RÜMEYSA-DURMAZ.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/2.-NİLAY-AYTEKİN.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/3.-HATİCE-KÜBRA-TOZ.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/5.-EDA-ARICI.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/6.-MELİKE-ZEYNEP-ER.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/7.-BEKİR-TAHA-GÜVENÇ.jpg' } },
                { source: { uri: 'https://headenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/8.-AYŞENUR-YILDIRIM.jpg' } }
            ]}
        />
    </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

But I want to make them dynamically. My service code to get image link is:

```
export const GetStudentReviews = (SuccessOperation, FailedOperation) => {
return(dispatch) => {
    const REF_DATABASE = FireBase.db.collection('StudentReviews').orderBy("DATE","desc");

    REF_DATABASE.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0)
        {
            const imageList  = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                imageList.push({
                    id:doc.id,
                    data:doc.data()
                })
            });
            dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:imageList } });
            SuccessOperation();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:[] } });
            FailedOperation();

        }
    }).catch(function(error) {

        dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:[] } });
        FailedOperation({errorMsg: error});
        console.log(error);
    });
}
};
```

and my firestore screenshots :
[image: Firestore_Collection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem after spending hours. I used "source:" instead of "data:" in imageList[] in my service code.

```
export const GetStudentReviews = (SuccessOperation, FailedOperation) => {
return(dispatch) => {
    const REF_DATABASE = FireBase.db.collection('StudentReviews');

    REF_DATABASE.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0)
        {
            const imageList  = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                imageList.push({
                    source: { uri:doc.data().STUDENT_REVIEW_URL },
                })

            });
            console.log("IMAGE_LIST",imageList);
            dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:imageList } });
            SuccessOperation({STUDENT_REVIEWS:imageList});
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:[] } });
            FailedOperation();

        }
    }).catch(function(error) {

        dispatch({ type: STUDENT_DISPATCH, payload:{ props:'StudentReviewListSection', value:[] } });
        FailedOperation({errorMsg: error});
        console.log(error);
    });
}
};
```

And My gallery code (imageLink is imageList which comes from service.):

```
 <SafeAreaView>
                {/* home screen navbar --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/}
                <View style={[{height: '100%%', backgroundColor:'white'}]}>
                    <Gallery
                        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black' }}
                        images={imageLink}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
```

That's solved my problem.